# need to take input from user and then delete even numbers from it even if they repeat themselves

Tags: python

```py
number_list = input("enter integers: ").split()
integer_list = [int(item) for item in number_list]

for i in integer_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        integer_list.remove(i)

print(integer_list)
```

this is the code that I came up with but when even numbers are repeated like: 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 then it will not remove all the 2's.

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify a list while you are iterating over it. This will lead to the iteration skipping entries, as you've seen. Instead, use the filtering built into [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
odd_numbers = [n for n in integer_list if n % 2 != 0]
```

gives `[3, 5]`